# How to transfer Jupyter settings to a different machine?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Providing my own answer, as this is not as obvious for people with little Linux experience.

Please add if you know any caveats.

Answer (score 2):

Copy folder `~/.jupyter` to the other machine. There are subfolders for notebook- and lab-specific settings.

Location:

```
/home/USERNAME/.jupyter # Linux
C:\Users\USERNAME\.jupyter # Windows
```